# How do online HTML editors prevent bugs from invalid user code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, editor, user-input

I have built a browser-based HTML/Markdown code editor, that seems to be working great for the most part. I have live rendering previews as the user updates code, etc. I already sanitize any `<script>` tags, but other elements such as `<div>` or `<style>` are allowed.

The problem is if the user saves the document with invalid HTML (i.e., unclosed `<style>` tags, etc.), upon reloading the document, the whole site will be inoperable due to my HTML elements being "eaten" by the unclosed tag in the user code.

**Question: Is there a solid strategy to render user code in an isolated container such that errors inside that container do not bleed out into the rest of the page?**

I am using Javascript with React. This seems like a use case for iFrames, but I have had it beaten into me that iFrames are *never* a good idea, and there is *always* a better way to do what you want to do.

Comment: You could use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to check for valid XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iframes are the perfect solution for problems like this. Over using them can be a problem on a page, but in this case it is the right tool for the job.

Also not sure why that was beaten into you, the `frame` tag is always bad, but `iframes` used sparingly are useful.